# Verifying T-FAT on WinCE 5.0

Tags: windows-ce, fat

We were having serious problems with corrupt files on our flash based FAT filesystem on WinCE 5.0. We believed that the files got corrupted because the WinCE device was turned off while writing to the FAT. Thus, we changed to T-FAT (transactional FAT).

What is the least time consuming way of verifying that our problems are solved?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at storage manager (which can be enabled in Control Panel if you are building your own O/S image).

Storage Manager has a UI for scanning, creating and repairing partitions.

You can also look at doing this programmatically: -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910657.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916710.aspx